# Laravel belongsTo where condition

Tags: laravel

I wanna filter today date, but it seems does not work. This function is a relation in class.

```
$manpower = Manpower::with(['pwra.purchaseOrder'])->get();
```

// Manpower Class

```
public function pwra()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pwra', 'pwra_uuid', 'pwra_uuid')->where('pwra_dt', Carbon::today());
}
```

// Pwra Class

```
public function purchaseOrder()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PurchaseOrder', 'purchase_order_uuid', 'purchase_order_uuid');
}
```

Without where case:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what s your pwra_dt date format?

Comment: that is 2020-07-20 (Y-m-d) in the database @Vikas Katariya

Comment: does the relationship work without the where clause? just to be sure that the problem in the where clause and not relationship itself

Comment: Yes, it works without where case @gbalduzzi

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Does it give you an error? Or is it an empty record? Is there a record for today's date?

Comment: It does not show error, just an empty record in pwra array if i add the where condition.

Comment: is pwra_dt just a date in the DB or a complete timestamp (i.e. it also has time)?

Comment: it is just a date in DB

Answer (score 0):

you should write query like this.

```
Model::with(['relationMethod'=>function($query){
            return $query->where('pwra_dt', date('Y-m-d'))->get();

        }]) ->get();
```

Comment: That is not controller

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `pwra_dt` is a timestamp, not just a date in the DB. Try this:

```php
public function pwra()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pwra', 'pwra_uuid', 'pwra_uuid')
      ->where('pwra_dt', '>=', Carbon::today())
      ->where('pwra_dt', '<', Carbon::tomorrow());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$manpower = Manpower::whereHas('pwra.purchaseOrder', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('pwra_dt', date('Y-m-d'));
})->get();
```